# How to load HTML String into iOS Safari on Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari

I am wondering how to launch iOS Safari browser from my App with HTML String (Not file, Not URL, just html string) instead of load into WKWebView or UIWebView?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

GCDWebServer?  make a server and open the local URL? not sure...